# Correct Way of Shaving Pubic Hair

Tags: hadith, taharah, fitrah, shaving

Assalaamualaikum , we have seen some hadiths on the importance of shaving pubic hair , but what is the right way of doing it? Is it ok if it is cut short with scissors?

**Narrated By Abu Huraira : I heard the Prophet saying. "Five practices are characteristics of the Fitra: circumcision, shaving the pubic hair, cutting the moustaches short, clipping the nails, and depilating the hair of the armpits."

Sahih al-Bukhari, The Book of Dress, Hadith Number:5952**

I've asked some friends though , and they say use blade. But blades seem a bit harsh . Similarly there is a ruling of shaving it off within 40 days. So I wanted to know the truth behind this "40 day" term . Please answer with a hadith.

So my question is , would scissors be alright to cut short with, and is there a 40 day threshold after which all good deeds are nulled?

Baarakallahu feekum.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and should be answered.. I lack a sufficient knowledge though. Anyone?

Comment: I have the answer with me .. ;) but i'll need to edit it to make it good for this site otherwise it will be out on terms of plagiarism

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question is that there isn't a "specific way" as we have for wudhu or ghusl . The process of shaving can be done anyhow provided you exercise precaution in doing so.

As regards whether it is an obligation or optional, the jurists (may Allaah have mercy upon them) agreed that it is a recommended act for men and women, however, some jurists (may Allaah have mercy upon them) are of the view that it is an obligation on the woman if her husband orders her to do so.

> Ibn Muflih (may Allaah have mercy upon him) said in Al-Aadaab
>   Ash-Shar'iyyah (the religious etiquettes): '**It is disliked to delay
>   shaving the pubic hair, plucking out armpit hair and trimming one's
>   moustache more than the stated period.**' The stated period is forty
>   days as Imaam Muslim(may Allaah have mercy upon him) reported that
>   Anas (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: "**The period that was
>   prescribed for us to trim our moustache, clip our nails, pluck out our
>   armpit hair and shave our pubic hair is forty days.**" Of course it
>   was the Prophet Sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam ( may Allaah exalt his
>   mention ) who determined for them this period of forty days, so it is
>   disliked to leave them longer than this period of time.

I had asked some knowledgeable people in my local area and they have said that it should be done in 40 days as in the above hadith. Though some people claim that it nullifies all your good deeds if not shaved within 40 days, the shaving of hair doesn't come as a compulsion for making your prayer valid, rather it is an act of Fitrah as mentioned in the hadith in the question. They are part of 'Taharah' (Cleanliness)

Regarding Scissors, the main objective is to cut them short, so the use of scissors is deemed permissible.

> It was said to Ahmad Bin Hanbal: What is your opinion of a man that
>   cuts down below with scissors and he does not cut it all off? He said:
>   I hope that is sufficient by the will of Allah. It was said: O Abu
>   Abdullah what do you say about a man who plucks his pubic hair? He
>   said: And does anyone have the strength to do this?. And shaving the
>   pubic hair, plucking it,removing it with lime or arsenic are all
>   permitted as long as the aim is fulfilled which is the removal of the
>   hair and cleaning the place.

But still it is better not to take chances by leaving them to grow because:

> On the authority of Abu Muhammad al-Hasan bin Ali bin Abi Talib, the
>   grandson of the Messenger of Allah, sallallahu ëalayhi wasallam, and
>   who is dearest to him, radiyallahu ëanhuma, who said: ìI committed to
>   memory from the Messenger of Allah, sallallahu ëalayhi wasallam, (the
>   following words): **Leave that about which you are in doubt for that about which you are in no doubt.** [Al-Tirmidhi and al-Nasaíi related
>   it, and al-Tirmidhi said: It is a good and genuine Hadith]

So better not take risks. Allah knows best!!
Baarakallahu Feekum. :)

Comment: I have a tiny q, anything to add about hairs on legs and hands or chests??

Comment: nope.. there's no need to shave that.. Only arm pits and private parts.