# Shaving in Islam

Tags: hadith, hair, shaving

Assalamualaikum, I am 15 and I have just found out about the ruling of shaving the pubic hair (men's). I wanted to know if you could simply just cut it very short with scissors rather than shaving it and also how should we approach removing hair from areas around the back passage?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://islamqa.info/en/2602) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/correct-way-of-shaving-pubic-hair) also. 
In addition, I will give you some tips.

1. Shave every two weeks
2. Don't wear tight underwear after shaving for 2-3 days. So its better to shave on Friday night and walk freely on the weekends.
3. There will be small cuts here and there. Remember that the skin on your scrotum is very hard and not easily cut by a blade.
4. Don't use aftershave lotion. Use a mix of 1 spoon honey and 2 drops lemon juice. Its good for the skin and small cuts.
5. Initially it might take you 1-2 hours. With practice you can do it in under 10 minutes.

It's really no big deal. All the best.