# Is it legitimate to shorten (not shave) ones pubic hair every two or three weeks?

Tags: sex, husband-wife

Peace be upon you all. I have a question regarding the shaving of pubic hair. As I understand it, one must shave his pubic hair at least every 40 days for hygienic reasons. However, within a month, I have very rapid growth of pubic hair. Normally, I would shave it, but my wife has made it clear in no uncertain terms that (my pardon if this offends anyone's sensibilities) she very much enjoys the existence of my pubic hair if it grows to about 2 week's length or more and that it makes our marital duties more enjoyable to her due to increased stimulation. I also believe it is my duty to please my wife and would enjoy doing so.

**My question:** Is it legitimate to shorten (not shave) ones pubic hair every two or three weeks to ensure that it never approaches the length of the 40-day limit?

I would continue to shave the shaft itself. This way, no dirt or sweat is able to accumulate and I would continue to please my wife in this manner.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongly suggest you to take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how this site works.

Comment: I assume you mean *pubic*, not *public*?

Comment: Related post http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/correct-way-of-shaving-pubic-hair?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear the hadith (like this version from sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/2/66)) about the 40 days or night period. Means in first place that one shouldn't wait more than forty days until he/she starts shaving/plucking or shortening any of the named body parts. So maybe one can wait 5 weeks while others can't even wait a couple of days before having the need to do this. This is considered as a kind of purification or good manner as you may find those hadiths in either of these chapters in hadith collections that should be the first priority in your reflections. Note that some of  this acts of cleaning are also considered as part of the inborn characteristics as quoted in jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/urn/629760) and sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/35/40).

What exactly you do or how you do it is up to you the most important is that your bodies doesn't get dirty or to keep it as clean as you can!