# Is it obligatory for Muslims to cut their pubic hair?

Tags: reference-request, hair, shaving

Is it obligatory for Muslim men / women to shave / cut pubic hair around the penis / vagina? If it is so, then what is the authentic hadith in its favor? Or is there any mention about this in the Qur'an?

Answer (score 1):

Found in [Sahih Bukhari #5891](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/108) and [Sahih Muslim #257](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/64), the hadith below suggest it is Sunnah to shave the pubic hair:

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ سَمِعْتُ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ الْفِطْرَةُ خَمْسٌ الْخِتَانُ، وَالاِسْتِحْدَادُ، وَقَصُّ الشَّارِبِ، وَتَقْلِيمُ الأَظْفَارِ، وَنَتْفُ الآبَاطِ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: I heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying. "Five practices are characteristics of the Fitra: circumcision, **shaving the pubic hair**, cutting the moustaches short, clipping the nails, and depilating the hair of the armpits."

The hadith below found in [Sahih Muslim #258](http://sunnah.com/muslim/2/66) suggests one should do it no longer than every 40 days.

> عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، قَالَ قَالَ أَنَسٌ وُقِّتَ لَنَا فِي قَصِّ الشَّارِبِ وَتَقْلِيمِ الأَظْفَارِ وَنَتْفِ الإِبْطِ وَحَلْقِ الْعَانَةِ أَنْ لاَ نَتْرُكَ أَكْثَرَ مِنْ أَرْبَعِينَ لَيْلَةً ‏.‏
>
> Anas reported: A time limit has been prescribed for us for clipping the moustache, cutting the nails, plucking hair under the armpits, shaving the pubes, that it **should not be neglected far more than forty nights.**

And [Correct Way Of Shaving Pubic Hair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/correct-way-of-shaving-pubic-hair) probably answers your question if it is obligatory or not.